# MDI Application, check if a child form with the same caption is open

Tags: delphi, mdi

I have a Delphi MDI application that has a customer search child form which can only be opened once (checking isAssigned), however the view / edit form can be opened multiple times so that the end user can open multiple customers at once (Tabbed), what I'd like to do is be able to stop them from opening the same customer record more than once, on the open of the customer form I set the caption to the customers account reference and if that form exists I would like to .BringToFront, if not I'll create it.

What would be the best way to achieve this please, as I'm scratching my head!

Thanks in advance.

```
procedure TfrmCustomerSearch.ViewCustomerExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  screen.cursor := crappstart;

  if not IsMDIChildOpen(frmMainMenu, 'frmCustomerView', pfrmCaption) then
    frmCustomerView := TfrmCustomerView.createform(nil,dmCustomerSearchfrm.FDQCustSearchreference.Value,cxGrid1DBTableView1.DataController.FocusedRecordIndex)
  else
    frmCustomerView.BringToFront;

  screen.cursor := crdefault;
end;

function TfrmCustomerSearch.IsMDIChildOpen(const AFormName: TForm; const AMDIChildName, AMDICaption : string): Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  for i := Pred(AFormName.MDIChildCount) DownTo 0 do
    if (AFormName.MDIChildren[i].name = AMDIChildName) then
    begin
      if (AFormName.MDIChildren[i].caption = AMDICaption) then
        begin
          Result := True;
          Break;
        end

    end;
end;
```

Comment: You will have to present minimal code which exposes the problem, other wise we can't help you.

Comment: added what I'm using so far, it may be something stupid, but I cannot see for looking

Comment: Using the FormName is a bad idea, there is no telling what it could be, use the classname in stead.

Comment: Also when you need a break to exit a loop, you have the wrong loop. Use a `while do`or a `repeat until`for this. This is not related to your problem though

Comment: MDIChildCount should be MDIChildCount - 1 in your loop.

Comment: @GuidoG break works on for loops - I am not sure what you are getting at. The only issue AFAIK is that the loop control variable is not maintained, but that is not applicable here.

Comment: @Dsm It has no relation to his problem I already stated that. Its just not logical to use an unconditional loop and then kill it at a condition anyway. There are conditional loops for that. About readability there are endless discussions lets not go there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something more like this instead:

```
procedure TfrmCustomerSearch.ViewCustomerExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Screen.Cursor := crAppStart;
  try
    frmCustomerView := TfrmCustomerView(FindMDIChildOpen(frmMainMenu, TfrmCustomerView, pfrmCaption));
    if frmCustomerView = nil then
      frmCustomerView := TfrmCustomerView.CreateForm(nil, dmCustomerSearchfrm.FDQCustSearchreference.Value, cxGrid1DBTableView1.DataController.FocusedRecordIndex);
    frmCustomerView.BringToFront;
  finally
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
  end;
end;

function TfrmCustomerSearch.FindMDIChildOpen(const AParentForm: TForm; const AMDIChildClass: TFormClass; const AMDICaption : string): TForm;
var
  i: Integer;
  Child: TForm;
begin
  Result := nil;
  for i := Pred(AParentForm.MDIChildCount) DownTo 0 do
  begin
    Child := AParentForm.MDIChildren[i];
    if Child.InheritsFrom(AMDIChildClass) and
       (Child.Caption = AMDICaption) then
    begin
      Result := Child;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much